# Transform Axes are all wrong

Tags: transforms

For some reason, in my Blender:

- Moving an object along X moves it forward and backwards (like Y)
- Moving along Y moves it up and down (like Z)
- Moving along Z moves it left and right (like X)

How do I fix this?

[image: Yeah, I like Pikuniku.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is right there in your screenshot :

[image]

You are moving your object along the 3D cursor.

To fix this just press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to reset your cursor position and rotation or change the transformation orientation since you probably (accidentally) set it to `Cursor` :

[image]
[image]

Change it back to `Global` again and everything should go back to normal.

**Further explanations**

You see, the 3D cursor, since `2.8`, has an orientation that can be used as a Transform orientation.

You can transform the 3D cursor under the N-panel > `View` and `3D Cursor` :

[image]

While in `2.7`, we could only change its location, now we can rotate it. If you check yours you will probably see that your rotations value for the 3D Cursor are not to the default value anymore :

[image]

Also, always be aware of the Transform Orientations, if the transform axes are not the way you expect them to be, it's most likely because you have the wrong Transform Orientation enabled. The shortcut for changing it is <kbd>.</kbd> (the period on the alphabetic pad not the number pad). They should be the first thing you check if you have problems like these.